# GeoIp shared memory

Tags: php, geolocation, ip, shared-memory, geoip

In  implementation of shared memory(GeoIpMaxMind extension) we can see that each time when i call this function it loads   all file in memory.

```
function geoip_load_shared_mem($file)
{
    $fp = fopen($file, "rb");
    if (!$fp) {
        print "error opening $file: $php_errormsg\n";
        exit;
    }
    $s_array = fstat($fp);
    $size = $s_array['size'];
    if (($shmid = @shmop_open(GEOIP_SHM_KEY, "w", 0, 0))) {
        shmop_delete($shmid);
        shmop_close($shmid);
    }
    $shmid = shmop_open(GEOIP_SHM_KEY, "c", 0644, $size);
    shmop_write($shmid, fread($fp, $size), 0);
    shmop_close($shmid);
}
```

So after load file in shared memory i can use geoip_open with shared memory flag.

```
$geoLiteCityData = GEOIPMAXMIND_ROOT . DS . 'GeoLiteCity.dat';
geoip_load_shared_mem($geoLiteCityData);
$gi = geoip_open($geoLiteCityData, GEOIP_SHARED_MEMORY);
```

That means that all operation with that database will be faster(because all my ip dabase in memory) but only for one application running. In next time(refresh page in browser) all file will be loaded in memory again according to geoip_load_shared_mem(it clears all memory cache and load file again). 
So the question is, how to use geoip shared memory for all application running.

I`ve done it in next way. Add checking for filesize chaging. Thx WizKid for helping

```
 $geoLiteCityData = GEOIPMAXMIND_ROOT . DS . 'GeoLiteCity.dat';

        if (!($shmid = @shmop_open(GEOIP_SHM_KEY, "a", 0, 0)) || shmop_size($shmid) != filesize($geoLiteCityData)) {
            geoip_load_shared_mem($geoLiteCityData);
        }
        $gi = geoip_open($geoLiteCityData, GEOIP_SHARED_MEMORY);
```

Comment: Try to open the shared memory for reading it. If it fails it is not there and you have to write it. If it is there just read it and use it

Comment: ok but is it possible that in those address in memory some other information will be, and i can read it but it will be not my database?

Comment: The first argument is the key. As long as you don't have code that write other stuff to the same key you should be fine